# Как динамично растягивать изображение по высоте внутри <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Допустим, есть страница test.html:

```
<img src="http://image1.thematicnews.com/uploads/images/68/22/64/02017/10/07/aa47713dff.jpg">
```

И есть страница index.html:

```
<iframe src="test.html"> </iframe>
```

С учетом того, что верстка адаптивная, и размер фрейма постоянно меняется, как можно растянуть изображение по высоте?

Возможно как-то через jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте высоту, и ширину изображения в 100%. Так же у body, и html.
Для того, что бы изображение сохраняло пропорции используйте object-fit: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
body,html,img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}

img{
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <img src="http://image1.thematicnews.com/uploads/images/68/22/64/02017/10/07/aa47713dff.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uk51qv4c/